# 403 Forbidden when connecting to pterodactyl websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, discord.js

I was wondering if someone could help me. I'm making a program that connects to pterodactyl's websocket but every time I try and connect it gives me a 403 - Forbidden. I've been researching this error for a few hours and I can't seem to find a fix. I'm using NodeJS v17.

Here's the code:

```
const embed = require('../../Configs/embed.json');
let PterodactylUser = require('../../Structures/Panel/PterodactylUser.js');
const SQL = require('../../Structures/Panel/SQL/SQL.js');
const mainConfig = require('../../Configs/config.json');
const WebSocket = require("ws");
module.exports = {
    name: 'Output',
    description: 'Sends live console output for the selected server!',
    category: 'Servers',
    enabled: true,
    options: [
        {
            name: "start",
            type: "SUB_COMMAND",
            description: "Starts sending console output for the server.",
            options: [
                {
                    name: "id",
                    type: "STRING",
                    description: "The ID of the server to link!",
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    name: "channel",
                    type: "CHANNEL",
                    channelTypes: ["GUILD_TEXT", "GUILD_NEWS"],
                    description: "The channel to link if not set uses current channel!"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    needsAPIKey: true,
    async execute(client, Discord, mainConfig, interaction, args) {
        const user = interaction.user || interaction.author;
        const channel = args.getChannel('channel') ? args.getChannel('channel') : interaction.channel;
        const serverId = args.getString('id');
        const mysql = new SQL();
        let apiKey = await mysql.getApiKey(user.id, interaction.guild.id);

        let res = await new PterodactylUser(apiKey).getWebsocket(serverId);

        const { socket, token } = res.data;

        const ws = new WebSocket(socket);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem caused by misconfigured panel access settings. You need to edit `/etc/pterodactyl/config.yml`

Citing the creator of PteroJS library from [my issue](https://github.com/PteroPackages/PteroJS/issues/9):

> The origin of the websocket request is not whitelisted. If you have access to Wings for the node you're using then set `allowed_origins` in "config.yml" to this:

```
allowed_origins:
  - "*"
```

> Otherwise, contact your panel administrator about it.